# How can I manually add a receiving address in MultiBit Classic Wallet - disconnected during confirmation

Tags: blockchain, address, multibit, receiving

Open to any suggestions... (Original Question is below and am trying advice from the first answer)

I am in the process of looking at all the deleted files on the USB disk where MultiBit resides using recovery software. Trying to determine where and if there was ever any private key to recover it.

There appears that the private key was not deleted as there is none for that time period so it was not received before the disruption. I recall it only started the confirmation process. I used the wallet infrequently. Previous time being last year (2014). Since there was no private key, could I not reestablish the wallet as it was at the about or prior to the point in time of the disruption and have it complete or run the blockchain to get the private key? There are numerous wallet files which I can see all with time dates which were deleted that are recoverable. I assume that it the rolling backup wallet files perhaps? I can even read the contents of the text ones and am seeing the actual receiving address (that I wanted to manually put into my wallets list) it is in a wallet file that is still deleted and recoverable probably. Ive not done anything as Im trying to figure out what procedure to do in what order as far as un-deleting files. I dont want to make a bigger mess either.

In addition I have a second copy of the same wallet on another USB drive which had the key from last use prior to generating the new receiving address which was disrupted when conformation was just starting. That second USB drive I did run the blockchain on and it did not have that receiving address...only synchronized and brought the chain up to date.

I would like to attempt to recover but am still trying to think through what would be most likely to work to or highest probability of success. I was thinking to how can I reestablish the wallet at or prior to time of disruption (with that receiving address) and then see if it will show the coins confirmation then save so there is a private key. Does this make any sense? OR is there a better more likely to get success approach? Any suggestions appreciated. thanks

-----------The Original Question below--------

How can I manually add a receiving address to my multibit classic wallet? Corruption of info file destroyed that address. After restoration back to last good copy, the receiving address (which I sent to the exchange) is no longer listed in my wallet in the list of receiving address in my multibit wallet. Due to an interruption in transfer during confirmation or power outage or usb disconnect (take your pick) that address disappeared.

The info file for that one time is totally corrupted from the power interruption. That probably explains the loss of the receiving address. My question and I should probably have been clearer about asking is "how can I manually add a receiving address to my multibit wallet receiving address list??" I know the receiving address and the precise amount as I sent it to the exchange and I can see it on the blockchain as one transaction...Just am missing the receiving address in my wallet and as I was watching it be confirmed when the sudden interruption happened before the key export or clean exit could happen. So I now have the address missing from the wallet list. The info file for that was totally unreadable and corrupted. I restored from the prior one. That was ok and ran the blockchain again. However that put me back in time before the new address was generated. The address was not there of course because of the info file corruption which has the address list and payment.

My question is how to manually to enter a receiving address into multibit wallet receiving address list? Can I put it into the info file? Tried it and didnt work... so please help.

How can I restore a specific missing address back into my wallet?? As I believe it would then reappear and complete the transaction if it was back on my address list. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may have the receiving address in one of the rolling backups.
Also, if your wallet is encrypted then when you create a new receiving address then an export of all the private keys is performed automatically (encrypted with the wallet password).

Where all the files are stored is described in:
https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_fileDescriptions.html

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Ive revised my question. I hope it clearer now.